# Comb_sort doesn't work in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I wrote a comb sort in Perl. Everything looks good, but the program doesn't work and the compiler doesn't show any errors. I would like to ask you for help. The code is:

```
@tab = (1,3,5,22,2,12,1);
$gap = scalar(@tab);
$replace = 1;

while ($gap>1 || $replace)
{
    $gap = ($gap * 10) / 13;
    if ($gap == 0)
    {        
        $gap = 1;
    }

    $replace = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i+$gap < $n ; $i++)
    {
        if ($tab[$i]>$tab[$i+$gap])
        {
            ($tab[$i], $tab[$i+$gap]) = ($tab[$i+$gap],$tab[$i]);
            $replace = 1;
        }
    }
}

print "Sorted array: @tab";
```

Comment: Numeric comparison is `==` in perl. `eq` is string comparison. You need `if( $gap == 0)`  Also `int` is a function. Perl doesn't do types.

Comment: No `use strict;` and no `use warnings;` and no `my` variables.  That bodes ill...  At the least, protect yourself from the implication that you don't know about these important tools by showing that you're using them.

Comment: Are you asking the compiler to show you as many errors as possible with `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: Note that you should show us an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It isn't even very hard.  You could create `my @tab = ( 19, 13, 2, 5, 3, 11, 17, 7 );` and `my $n = scalar(@tab);`  and a printing function that shows the before and after state of the array. It's an extra 10 lines of code, but makes all the difference in how well your question will be received.  It is not unknown for there to be problems in the supporting code...showing it means we can fix it.  Did you print `$gap`?  `swap` isn't a core function; have you tested it? Show it!

Comment: Ok, I improved the upper code. Earlier I copied unconverted function (I 'translate' it from C++), my mistake. Now the sort still doesn't work - I can't print a count of $gap. What can I do? I also set "use strict" and "use warnings". The compiler inform only, that my variables requires "explicit package (I wrote my first larger program in Perl, and I use many times the same names of variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revised code uses `$n` but never sets it.  If you used `use warnings;` and `use strict;`, you would have known about that problem.  With those directives, I get:

```
$ perl comb.pl
Global symbol "$n" requires explicit package name at comb.pl line 20.
Execution of comb.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
$
```

There are only 5 variables in the code, including the `$n`, so there's only a need for `my` to appear 5 times.

With `$n` set to the initial value of `$gap` (aka `scalar(@tab)`), the code sorts your data set OK, and mine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tab = ( 19, 13, 2, 5, 3, 11, 17, 7 );
#my @tab = (1,3,5,22,2,12,1);
my $gap = scalar(@tab);
my $replace = 1;
my $n = $gap;

print "Unsorted array: @tab\n";

while ($gap>1 || $replace)
{
    $gap = ($gap * 10) / 13;
    $gap = 1 if ($gap == 0);
    print "Gap = $gap\n";

    $replace = 0;
    for (my $i=0; $i+$gap < $n; $i++)
    {
        if ($tab[$i]>$tab[$i+$gap])
        {
            ($tab[$i], $tab[$i+$gap]) = ($tab[$i+$gap],$tab[$i]);
            $replace = 1;
        }
    }
}

print "Sorted array: @tab\n";
```

Sample run — your data

```
Unsorted array: 1 3 5 22 2 12 1
Gap = 5.38461538461539
Gap = 4.14201183431953
Gap = 3.18616294947656
Gap = 2.45089457652043
Gap = 1.88530352040033
Gap = 1.45023347723102
Gap = 1.11556421325463
Gap = 0.85812631788818
Sorted array: 1 1 2 3 5 12 22
```

Sample run — my data

```
Unsorted array: 19 13 2 5 3 11 17 7
Gap = 6.15384615384615
Gap = 4.73372781065089
Gap = 3.64132908511607
Gap = 2.80102237316621
Gap = 2.15463259474323
Gap = 1.65740968826403
Gap = 1.27493052943387
Gap = 0.980715791872205
Sorted array: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

If you plan to ask any more questions about Perl on SO, please make sure you've fixed all the obvious problems reported by using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` — or, if you can't, your question should be about how to fix the specific warning or error you're getting.

Please remember to study how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Comment: Thank you :). Now everythig works like I wanted to. I will remember your advices.